# Burlando o ReCaptcha

Tags: vb.net, segurança, recaptcha

Tenho um site de um cliente feito em VB.net e ele tem um formulário de fale conosco onde tem um ReCaptcha 2 do Google nele e hoje teve um cidadão que ta conseguindo enviar mensagens neste formulário e passando pelo ReCaptcha sem nenhum problema. Ele tá enviando sempre do mesmo IP por enquanto. Tem como melhorar a segurança neste formulário para ele parar?

Comment: Tem como você postar o código desse formulário? Se ele estiver de fato quebrando o recaptcha, é mais complicado, mas talvez ele esteja simplesmente evitando (*bypassing*) o mesmo devido a alguma configuração incorreta seja na própria página ou no código do servidor (onde ele processa as informações enviadas pela página).

Comment: "Cerquei minha casa mas os coiotes continuando entrando, como posso deixar minha casa mais segura?" É igualmente impossível responder sem examinar a casa. Posta o código ou a URL pra gente também tentar hackear e descobrir a falha.

Comment: "Posta o código ou a URL pra gente também tentar hackear e descobrir a falha." Acho que se ele postar a URL e muita gente achar a brecha o cliente dele não vai gostar... Mas você e o mgibsonbr estão certos, claro.

Comment: O caminho da solução não é o sistema de captcha, onde você não tem nenhum controle e sempre terá que esperar novas atualizações do google captcha. Sistemas de captcha inclusive o do google não são soluções de segurança, são apenas complementos.Sempre haverá formas simples de burlar o captcha, minha dica é que você trabalhe com sistema de intervalos no formulário e identificação de ip, blacklist`s,etc... nenhum pentelho resiste a isso. Vai por mim !!